# @composite vs flatmap in complex strategies

Tags: python, property-based-testing, python-hypothesis

hypothesis allows two different ways to define derived strategies, `@composite` and `flatmap`. As far as I can tell the former can do anything the latter can do. However, the [implementation](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis/blob/e05902a7851fd5e45a1eeb8605446688c261a762/hypothesis-python/src/hypothesis/extra/numpy.py#L399-L403) of the numpy `arrays` strategy, speaks of some hidden costs

```py
    # We support passing strategies as arguments for convenience, or at least
    # for legacy reasons, but don't want to pay the perf cost of a composite
    # strategy (i.e. repeated argument handling and validation) when it's not
    # needed.  So we get the best of both worlds by recursing with flatmap,
    # but only when it's actually needed.
```

which I assume means worse shrinking behavior but I am not sure and I could not find this documented anywhere else. So when should I use `@composite`, when `flatmap` and when should I go this halfway route as in the implementation linked above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@composite` and `.flatmap` are indeed exactly equivalent - anything you can do with one you can also do with the other, and it will have the same performance too.

I actually wrote that comment, and the reason is that we only *sometimes* want to use a flatmap/composite, but *always* want to carefully validate our logic.  The way I've set it up, we can avoid calling the validators more than once by using `.flatmap` - which would require a second function definition if we wanted to use `@composite`.

(there's also an issue of API style in that those arguments are almost always values, but can sometimes be strategies.  We now ban such APIs based largely on the confusion `arrays()` has caused, in favor of letting users write their own `.flatmap`s)

Comment: Makes sense. Can you explain what you mean by "the validators"? Searching for `validator` in the docs only produces two hits, both of which do not really explain anything. And is it accepted best practice not to take strategies as arguments but instead `.flatmap` everything?

Comment: Internally, we check that e.g. all the arguments are of an allowed type - but obviously once that validator has passed once, we don't need to run it again for every example.

Best practice is that any particular argument can accept a value *xor* a strategy.  For example in `st.datetimes()`, `min_value` must always be a datetime (never a strategy), and `timezones` must always be a strategy for `tzinfo` objects (never such an object).  Deciding which to use is based on frequency and comparing the inconvenience of `st.just(...)` vs `x.flatmap(...)`.