# How to build a strategy to create array of tuples with pairs of identical values?

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

I'd like to generate a strategy for NumPy testing with an output like:

```
array([[-2, -2],
       [-3, -3],
       [5,  5],
       [-1, -1]], dtype=int16)
```

What I tried was:

```
import numpy as np
from hypothesis.strategies import integers
from hypothesis.extra.numpy import arrays
arrays(np.int16, (4,2), elements=integers(-10, 10)).example()
```

Unfortunately, I can't make values inside tuples identical so the query above returns:

```
array([[ 5,  5],
       [-7,  5],
       [ 5,  5],
       [ 5,  5]], dtype=int16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that if I need to control content *within* an existing strategy's structure (e.g. pairs of identical values *within* an array) I need to skip that strategy for lower level ones with which I can build a "ready-made" value that can seed the type I care to generate.

Let's leverage that numpy.array accepts a list of lists to create an array. Let's also assume you want each row to be unique, as your example does not show duplicate rows. If that is not desired, remove the `unique_by=str` from the `depth_strategy` definition

1. Generate an integer and create a list of that value repeated a number of times to meet the WIDTH.
2. Generate a list of a DEPTH length of the kind of lists we created in the first step.
3. Combine the two strategies by nesting them.
4. Feed the result of the third step into numpy.array, making sure the dtype matches the strategy used to generate values in the first step.

```
# %%
"""Hypothesis strategy for array of tuples with pairs of identical values."""
from hypothesis import given, settings, strategies as st

import numpy as np

WIDTH = 2
DEPTH = 4
MIN_VALUE = -10
MAX_VALUE = 10

# Build the row - Here for clarification only
width_strategy = st.integers(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE).map(
    lambda i: tuple(i for _ in range(WIDTH))
)

# Build the array of rows - Here for clarification only
depth_strategy = st.lists(
    width_strategy, min_size=DEPTH, max_size=DEPTH, unique_by=str
).map(lambda lot: np.array(lot, dtype=np.int64))

# All-in-One
complete_strategy = st.lists(
    st.integers(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE).map(
        lambda i: tuple(i for _ in range(WIDTH))
    ),
    min_size=DEPTH,
    max_size=DEPTH,
    unique_by=str,
).map(lambda lot: np.array(lot, dtype=np.int64))


@settings(max_examples=10)
@given(an_array=complete_strategy)
def create_numpy_array(an_array):
    """Turn list of lists into numpy array."""
    print(f"A numpy array could be:\n{an_array}")


create_numpy_array()
```

This generates something like:

```
A numpy array could be:
[[ 3  3]
 [ 9  9]
 [-5 -5]
 [ 0  0]]
A numpy array could be:
[[ 3  3]
 [-2 -2]
 [ 4  4]
 [-5 -5]]
A numpy array could be:
[[ 7  7]
 [ 0  0]
 [-2 -2]
 [-1 -1]]
```

Note that I set the max_examples to 10 as Hypothesis gives a higher occurrences ratio to values it deems "troublesome", such as zero, NaN, Infinity and such. So example() or a lower number of examples would probably generate a lot of 2x4 arrays of all zeroes. Fortunately the unique_by constraint helps us here.

Comment: I just realized that I should have lifted the np.array into the mapping on the outer strategy. I have updated the code above to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you. Eventually, I reused your logic and compose the strategy inside the @composite component. I will reach out to the maintainers of the hypothesis about creating scientific heavy cook-book examples.

Comment: On your note of moving it into an @composite decorated function. I'm still trying to fully grasp the consequences of the [composite v flatmap discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59342856/composite-vs-flatmap-in-complex-strategies) and how it might apply to strategies like this one. It might be worth a look if you haven't looked at it yet.

Comment: `unique_by=lambda l: str(l)` -> `unique_by=str`.
@MarcinCharęziński, we'd be very happy to link to or merge a cookbook, the problem is finding time to write one!

Answer (score 0):

Without looking too much into what np has to offer, you can just generate the tuples using a generator:

```py
tuple_list = [tuple(a) for a in arrays(np.int16, (4,2), elements=integers(-10,10)).example()]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but that function returns an array of tuples that does not satisfy conditions stated in the original question.

Comment: "How to build a strategy to *create array of tuples* with pairs of identical values?"

I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for...

Answer (score 0):

No sure this is what you're after, but the `arrays` from `hypothesis.extra.numpy` doesn't appear to have options to duplicate values.

You can just construct the array you need like this:

```
import numpy as np
from hypothesis.strategies import integers
strat = integers(10, -10)
np.array([[x, x] for x in [strat.example() for _ in range(4)]], np.int16)
```

Example result:

```
array([[-9, -9],
       [ 0,  0],
       [-2, -2],
       [ 0,  0]], dtype=int16)
```

If you don't like that the `2` dimension is baked in, you can have both be parameters like this:

```
def get_array(rows, cols, strat):
    np.array([[x]*cols for x in [strat.example() for _ in range(rows)]], np.int16)


get_array(4, 2, integers(-10, 10))
```

Comment: Note: at this point, you may wonder why use `hypothesis` at all - but you didn't provide a context, so you may want to for specific reasons.

Comment: "arrays from hypothesis.extra.numpy doesn't appear to have options to duplicate values."

I feel like there is a way to create such a strategy. Either by build own strategy or augmenting or composing the existing one.